# failed to start 'instance-controller' service on EMR master node

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I started observing below validation error on EMR console,
[image]

Upon checking the status of the instance controller service, observed that

`sudo systemctl status instnace-controller.service` output is not consistent, it varies between **running** and **auto-restart**.

Master node system logs shows;

```
(console) 2023-02-03 21:55:23 About to start instance controller.
(console) 2023-02-03 21:55:23 Listing currently running instance controllers:
hadoop    8439     1  0 21:55 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash -l /usr/bin/instance-controller
hadoop    8510  8439  0 21:55 ?        00:00:00 /etc/alternatives/jre/bin/java -Xmx1024m -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 -server -cp /usr/share/aws/emr/instance-controller/lib/*:/home/hadoop/conf -Dlog4j.defaultInitOverride aws157.instancecontroller.Main
hadoop    8541  8439  0 21:55 ?        00:00:00 grep -i instance
root      8542  8439  0 21:55 ?        00:00:00 sudo tee -a /emr/instance-state/console.log-2023-02-03-21-55 /dev/console
oozie    26477     1 26 21:53 ?        00:00:22 /etc/alternatives/jre/bin/java -Xmx1024m -Xmx1024m -Doozie.home.dir=/usr/lib/oozie -Doozie.config.dir=/etc/oozie/conf -Doozie.log.dir=/var/log/oozie -Doozie.data.dir=/var/lib/oozie -Doozie.instance.id=ip-10-111-24-159.pvt.lp192.cazena.com -Doozie.config.file=oozie-site.xml -Doozie.log4j.file=oozie-log4j.properties -Doozie.log4j.reload=10 -Djava.library.path= -cp /usr/lib/oozie/embedded-oozie-server/*:/usr/lib/oozie/embedded-oozie-server/dependency/*:/usr/lib/oozie/lib/*:/usr/lib/oozie/libtools/*:/usr/lib/oozie/libext/*:/usr/lib/oozie/embedded-oozie-server:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/* org.apache.oozie.server.EmbeddedOozieServer
root     27455     1 42 21:54 ?        00:00:35 /etc/alternatives/jre/bin/java -Xmx1024m -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 -server -cp /usr/share/aws/emr/instance-controller/lib/*:/home/hadoop/conf -Dlog4j.defaultInitOverride aws157.logpusher.Main /etc/logpusher/logpusher.properties
(console) 2023-02-03 21:55:23  Displaying last 10 lines of instance controller logfile: 
2023-02-03 21:55:17,719 INFO main: isV2FrameworkEnabled: false, extraInstanceData.numCandidates: 1
2023-02-03 21:55:17,735 WARN main: Invalid metrics information null fetched from checkpoint, will start continuing from current moment instead.
2023-02-03 21:55:17,735 INFO main: Initialized YARN checkpointing state with ckpFileAvl: true, ckpInfo: [ lastCkpTs(0), totalHdfsBytesReadCompletedApps(0), totalHdfsBytesWrittenCompletedApps(0), totalS3BytesReadCompletedApps(0), totalS3BytesWrittenCompletedApps(0)]
2023-02-03 21:55:17,745 ERROR main: Thread + 'main' failed with error
java.lang.RuntimeException: LocalStartupState is FAILED, so not allowing instance controller to start
    at aws157.instancecontroller.common.InstanceConfigurator.hasAlreadyBeenConfigured(InstanceConfigurator.java:124)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.common.InstanceConfigurator.<init>(InstanceConfigurator.java:100)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.InstanceController.<init>(InstanceController.java:223)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.Main.runV1Framework(Main.java:239)
    at aws157.instancecontroller.Main.main(Main.java:222)
```

I tried restarting service multiple time with
`sudo systemctl start instance-controller.service`, rebooted the node hoping that service will start back after reboot. But it is not working. (Btw, this worked on lower environment)

Jobs on the cluster are running fine though without any issues, but I am not able to see application logs pushed to S3 or on console.
Need inputs on how to restart instance controller service.

Comment: Hi, I am on the EMR team, but I can't say I've ever seen anything like this. If you can provide your cluster ID, I might be able to help. Is your master instance perhaps running out of disk space (particularly on the /emr partition, which is what instance-controller uses)?

Comment: @JonathanKelly I started becuase of '/emr' reaching 100% but then I cleaned it up, now it is 50% but still seeing the issue.

Comment: Hmm, I think this is pretty unusual for the /emr partition to fill up like this. It usually manages its space well and rotates/cleans up logs in order to conserve space in that critical partition. Would you be able to provide a cluster ID? It's possible for EMR team members and AWS Support to look into what is taking up space in this partition, given a cluster ID.